# Segmentation fault when importing pylab in a python script

Tags: python

I have installed Ubuntu 8.10. I am using python 2.6.4. I have installed the following packages

networkx 1.0rc1
matplotlib 0.99.1.2
scipy 0.7.1
numpy 1.3

when I write the following statement in my code

```
import pylab
```

Also this statement gives a segmentation fault

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I receive a segmentation fault. What do I do?
The same code works perfectly well on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

try running python through gdb. The top frame of the stacktrace is the (assumed) origin of the segmentation fault. This should give you a rough idea what to write in a bug report. If all of the above packages are from the ubuntu repositories, there should be a good chance that someone in the ubuntu community has an idea of what's going on.